# Saving cleaned-up intersection points into shapefile

Tags: osmnx

I have a problem with saving some work to shapefile.

I did the Intersection Clean-Up for an area I'm working on, exactly as been described in this [tutorial](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples/blob/master/notebooks/14-clean-intersection-node-clusters.ipynb)
and it worked perfectly fine.

Now I would like to export the outcoming nodes of the intersections to a shapefile to further work with it on Qgis.

I tried the following:

`ox.save_graph_shapefile(G_proj, filename='network-shape17')`

But I only got nodes and edges from before the clean-up and not the cleaned up nodes, I would like to have.

I hope someone can help me getting the cleaned-up Intersection points as a shapefile.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [the docs](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.simplify.clean_intersections), the `clean_intersections` function returns a geopandas GeoSeries of the cleaned-up intersection points, rather than altering the graph's topology itself (though note this [PR](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/pull/249) that would add such capabilities). Accordingly, you can just save this returned result to disk natively with [geopandas](http://geopandas.org/io.html#writing-spatial-data).